# The best way to test appsettings.release.json locally in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, appsettings

I have appsettings.release.json how do I test it locally while debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new IConfiguration object that only has appsettings.release.json registered.

```
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Release.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
```

Now you can debug your code and use the new Iconfiguration object to test your release settings.

```
Configuration[ApplicationInsight:ConnectionString]
```